# Naming DataFrame after list value in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two `.csv` files I wish to load to `DataFrames`:

```
def loader(y):
    return pd.read_csv(y, header='infer',  encoding="ISO-8859+-1")

names = ['currency', 'debt_ratio']

for name in names:
    i = loader(name +'.csv')
```

I'd like the name of the `DataFrame` to be the same as the name of `.csv` file. However, whenever I try something like the below, it just names the `DataFrame` as 'name':

```
for name in names:
    name = loader(name +'.csv')
```

I appreciate this is likely a very simple fix - but I've spent hours trying to work it out to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *safe* way to do this, is to use a dictionary:

```
df_dict = {}  
for name in names:
    df_dict[name] = loader(name +'.csv')
```

The dictionary maps your csv names to the actual dataframes in memory. This is safe and does not pollute `globals()`.

As a note on how to use this, if you want to reference the particular dataframe for `currency`, just use `df_dict['currency']`:

```
df_temp = df_dict['currency']
```